# Upload file using Selenium WebDriver - Unable to interact with Dialog window C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to upload file using `Selenium WebDriver`. The problem is that selenium not sending file path to the dialog window. I'm using `SendKeys()`. Here is my code:

```
Click.DsrSubmitNewActivityToolPage.AttachmentButton();
Thread.Sleep(4000);
Actions action = new Actions(PageElements.Driver);
action.SendKeys("C:/Users/gk/Documents/Test/Test Test.docx");
action.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
Thread.Sleep(4000);
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="activity yui3-g">
   <div class="label yui3-u-1-5">
       <span>Attachment:</span>
   </div>
   <div class="yui3-u-4-5">
       <input id="fileID" type="file" name="file"/>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="pointValueContainer" class="activity yui3-g" style="display:none">
<span class="label">Notes</span>
<div class="activity">
<p>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the `html` as well?

Comment: @Gala_De you are missing `.Perform()` method call to complete actions.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Vivek Singh. I attached the html for your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are performing `SendKeys()` on driver/root instead of the target element.

You need to find the target file tag and use `SendKeys()` on that.
EG:

```
public void Test(string filepath)
{
    By byCss = By.CssSelector("your selector");
    //explicit wait to make sure the element is visible
    new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(byCss));
    Driver.FindElement(byCss).SendKeys(filepath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to interact with the native file dialog, then Selenium cannot achieve that.

You could use something like AutoIT to automate the dialog BUT I would recommend strongly against it; you will hit cross browser and scalability issues later.

Instead, you can perform send_keys on the  associated to the file upload.  Look in the html, there will definitely be an  in the file upload control.

Just by using send_keys to insert the path of the file will result in the upload taking place.
You do not have to use ActionBiilders

Answer (score 0):

So since its type **file** u can directly perform `driver.FindElement(By.Id("fileID")).SendKeys(filepath);`

But do remember while using Actions class you need to call `Build` (if you are going for multiple actions so in order to combine them) followed by `Perform` (to perform the provided actions).

Though i am a **java guy** but what i have seen in sendkeys method if you are providing filepath with a space, it won't be able to get the file so i would suggest to create a file object and in sendkeys send file's `absolutePath`.